# Conditional output in MYSQL groupb function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

So I have a table in this form

```
    +----+-----+
    | id | Val |
    +----+-----+
    |  1 |  20 |
    |  1 |  30 |
    |  2 |   0 |
    |  2 |  80 |
    |  3 |  45 |
    |  3 |  60 |
    |  4 |   0 |
    |  4 |  30 |
    +----+-----+
```

I want to do a groupby on the id and the sum the values in the Val column. Only, if one of the values is zero, the resultant sum should also be zero

For the above table, the output would be

```
    +----+-------+
    | id |SumVal |
    +----+-------+
    |  1 |  50   |
    |  2 |   0   |
    |  3 | 105   |
    |  4 |   0   |
    +----+-------+
```

I've tried using conditional statements(CASE and IF) inside the sum function but those conditions seem to work only on the individual elements.

Any pointers ?

Comment: what do you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `SUM` and `IF`:

```
SELECT id, (SUM(val) * IF(val = 0, 0, 1)) AS SumVal FROM idval GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I was trying to use the IF condition inside the SUM function. 

SUM(IF val = 0, 0)

Now it looks obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Check This Simple Query.

```
        select id ,SUM(val)
        from #Table
        where val=0
        group by ID 
        union
        select id ,SUM(val)
        from #Table
        where id not in (select id from #Table where val=0)
        group by ID
```

> OutPut :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select id,if(cast(val as signed),sum(val),0) as total from tbl_name group by id;
```